# How to structure REST requests with embedding when it depends on the authenticated user?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I have a resource `group`; `GET /groups/123` returns:

```
{id:123, name: "My group"}
```

I also have group members; `GET /groups/123/members` or `GET /members?group=123`:

```
[{id:201,name:"Jack"},{id:202,name:"Jill"}]
```

For efficiency, I aggregate subordinate data into `GET /groups/123` request, as well as the current user's permissions on the group:

```
{id:123,name:"My group",admin:true,members:[{id:201,name:"Jack"},{id:202,name:"Jill"}]}
```

The actual number of user-dependent fields is much higher than these two (`members` and `admin`) and much harder to manage; this is just an example.

Here is the problem: the results of `GET /groups/123` will now vary based on who the authenticated user is. This makes managing it rather messy (and somewhat un-RESTful). For example:

- "Jack" is an admin, he will get `admin:true` and will see all of the members
- "Jill" is not an admin, she will get `admin:false` (or `undefined`) and not see members, or only a public subset

How do I structure my URLs/resources so that a request will always return *either* the same data *or* a `403` denied because the user does not have the right?

UPDATE:

For some clarification, I can see how I might modify the URL or query, e.g. `GET /groups/123?admin=true` to say, "get me the admin stuff". The problem is that I don't *know* that I am admin *until* I get it.

When I make a `GET` call, my current question is actually 3 questions:

- get me group 123 info
- check if I am admin and mark it
- if I am admin, get me more info like members

I could split these into three requestes:

1. `GET /groups/123`
2. `GET /groups/123/permissions/1` (I am user 1)
3. `GET /groups/123/adminFields (if I am admin)

But then I have 3 requests (probably many more) and have lost all of my aggregation benefits.

Answer (score 0):

There was already a question about such issue. See this link: [Different REST representations of same resource for different authenticated users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525070/different-rest-representations-of-same-resource-for-different-authenticated-user).

I think that there is an issue if the structure of returned representations aren't the same for admin or non admin.

If they differ, you should add an additional resource to provide the additional hints for admin.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks for the link. When I first saw it, I thought, "shoot! Did I ask it already?!?" Thankfully, it wasn't me. I will look at the link and either update or mark as correct.

Comment: The other link has two options: explicitly request it via a separate URL or query params (I do that elsewhere in my app); or have a link to the admin info. I could do both... but I might not even know if I am admin until I make the request.